# Using head light as bar light?

Tags: lighting

Lately I have been using a head lamp, installed on my helmet, while commuting to work.

For improving safety, and considering that I have a bar fixture for a handlebar bag which is unused for my commute, I was thinking of having a 3D printed thingy to attach the head lamp to the steering bar via the fixture.

Is there any shortcoming on this?

Comment: I just got back from a quick 8 miles at night.  Farm country roads and almost no cars, you can't beat it.  Anyway, I use one light on the handlebars and one on my head, one to illuminate where the bike is going and one to illuminate whatever I'm looking at, like my watch for example, or cows and chickens.  I'd hate to have to choose one light or the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the beam shape. My commuting head torch has a narrow beam. While I mainly use it in addition to a handlebar light I have ridden with just the head torch, and found that I'm constantly scanning the beam. You can't do that on the bars. Other head torches aren't much use for illuminating the road in front, as the light pattern is too wide, but some would be perfect (often the more expensive ones).

Unless your access to a 3d printer is free, a cheap light might be more cost effective and then you'd still have the head torch. The mount would have to be quite robust and well fitted to avoid vibrations misaligning the light.

Comment: I agree with this. You want a wide beam on your handlebars or fork mounted and a narrow beam on your head.

Answer (score 3):

Printing a part from plastic can work but its not something I'd use a structural component.  Instead I'd look at folding something up out of strip steel or aluminium.

Head lamps are good in that they follow your face-direction.  So you can aim them at something.

Bar lamps are good because they light up where your wheel is about to roll.

Personally I run both head and bar lights for these reasons.  Batteries are cheap, recharging is easy, and problem avoidance is a good idea.

Do explore the legal allowances in your area - here in NZ we're allowed up to two lights on the bars, only one of which may blink.   Personally I have exactly that, plus one on the fork and two on the helmet.  I choose to consciously have more lights than permitted - you make your own choice.